# How to request a value from a column by filtering a range

Tags: filter, max, min, flatten, google-query-language

Having in column C country names and in range E:N population in different years
I try to find the country with the max population ever (so in the range E2:N43)
tried with queries below wihout success:

```
=QUERY(A1:N43,"select C WHERE '"&MAX(E2:N43)&"' IN '"&E2:N43)
=QUERY(A1:N43,"select C WHERE '"&MAX(E2:N43)&"' = '"&E2:N43&"' ")
```

What's wrong?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 here is the  [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwIXD8B3vcNoEyQ7NmcYgDJhkKeaNzNhNqJj8ZTF61s/edit?usp=sharing)
See notes in column Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(E2:N&"×"&C2:C, C2:C<>"")), "×"), 1, 1), 1))
```

max:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(E2:N&"×"&C2:C, C2:C<>"")), "×"), 1, 0), 1))
```

[image]